# Required Outbound Email Functionality after web 8 installation

Tags: web8, outbound-email

We have production CMS server which is using Tridion 2013 sp1.We want to setup a web8 development CMS server using production cms database.After installing web 8 on development server using 2013 SP1 Production CMS database outbound email related windows service like "Tridion Outbound E-mail Mailer","Tridion outbound Email Collect Tracking Data" etc is missing in new installation.How can we get this services using Web 8 fresh installation.

Answer (score 3):

Outbound E-mail is considered a legacy feature now, so you had to pass a flag to the installer for it to be installed.

[From the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-33187D11-0B59-4ABB-A67E-C448FD952F04):

> start the installer executable from a command line and add the key-value pair LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE

Comment: Thank you @Peter. So is it ok to run the installer again with the LEGACY_VISIBLE switch and only select OE during the installation?

Comment: Yes, it will add it to the existing setup.